# How to execute command Post run in github actions?

Tags: yaml, workflow, pipeline, github-actions

Is there a way to execute a command post-run, no matter if the previous status was a success or failed something similar to post and always syntax in jenkinsfile

I have tried **continue-on-error: true** but this will make failed step as passed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [Job Status Check Functions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#job-status-check-functions) with [dependencies between jobs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idneeds).

For example:

```
jobs:
  job1:
    continue-on-error: true
    # Do your stuff here
  job2:
    if: ${{ always() }}
    # Execute your post run command here
```

I've created a sample workflow to show [something similar working here](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/16-conditional.yml) using `continue-on-error` with this condition.

You'll see in that example that even with an error on job2, job3 is still executed afterwards.
This [workflow run](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/actions/runs/977124114) returns something like this (without the workflow failing and always executing the post run commands on job 3):

[image: Example]